# storing the count of rows or just count the rows?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

To exemplify my situation, think of a Question & Answer platform like stackoverflow. Basically there are `questions` and `answers` tables. What is the best practice for displaying the number of answers of a specific question?

- Should there be a "count column" in the `questions` table? Every time new answer is added or deleted "count column" should be updated.
- Or just do count the rows of the answers using MySQL in the `answers` table? My concern in this option is the load to database but I am not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not worry about load on the database unless you actually find it to be a problem. In fact, the option of keeping a count requires an additional update on every CRUD operation, so I would think that would be more overhead than an occasional count. Go with [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) first, and if you find a problem, then fix it :)

Answer (score 1):

I would keep it simple for now, and use `COUNT` to return the rows, but there are some caveats that you should be aware of.

MySQL is able to use an index for `COUNT(*)` queries, so MySQL won't have to hit the actual table row data to get a count. The caveat is that if you attempt a `COUNT(column)` query against a column that allows NULL values, MySQL will still have to scan the rows to count the NULL values, since NULL values aren't stored in an index.

Therefore, be certain that you ask for `COUNT` against columns that are defined as NOT NULL.

MyISAM tables store row counts, so a COUNT(*) query for all rows in a table is super lightweight. This is possible since MyISAM locks the whole table, forcing sequential updates. Hence, MyISAM, always knows how many rows.