# Storing count in the main table

Tags: sql, performance, count

I have three database tables,

1. `Users`   ( UserID, ... )
2. `Entries` ( EntryID, ... )
3. `Likes`   ( UserID, EntryID, ... )

My question is easy. Should I use a `LikeCount` column in the table `Entries` or use a `SELECT COUNT(*)` statement everytime I need it from `Likes` table? Which one is the better practice?

It's probably duplicate with this  question: [storing the count of rows or just count the rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518637/storing-the-count-of-rows-or-just-count-the-rows) The given answer to that  question is basically don't use `LikeCount` and count every time you need instead. However they do not give satisfactory answers to the following questions:

1. What is the bad consequences of storing count in the table
2. What is the performance analyzes of these two different approaches if I need to count likes  very frequently in my application

PS: I use SQL Server 2008 if it is important

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**What is the bad consequences of storing count in the table:**

There are 2 problems with this approach:

1. You have to use database triggers or application code to keep the count up to date as the Likes table changes.
2. If you ever get #1 wrong, you have to deal with the fact that the LikeCount might not actually match the number of likes.

**What is the performance analyzes of these two different approaches if I need to count likes very frequently in my application:**

I believe that if you created an index for the Likes table, most database engines will be able to answer a COUNT(*) query very quickly without referencing the actual table.  Basically, in the index the database keeps track of how many rows match a given key, which is the same thing as your LikeCount.

If you are going to write a query like:

```
SELECT count(*) from Likes where EntryID=45;
```

Then your index has to be on EntryID.

But, if you are going to write a query like:

```
SELECT count(*) from Likes where EntryID=45 and deleted=False;
```

Then your index has to be on (EntryID, deleted).